# Computing scikit-learn multiclass ROC Curve with cross validation (CV)

Tags: python, machine-learning, attributes, scikit-learn, roc

I want to evaluate my classification models with a ROC curve. I'm struggling with computing a multiclass ROC Curve for a cross-validated data set. There is no division in train and test set, because of the cross-validation. 
Underneath, you can see the code I already tried.

```
   scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False) 

   enc = LabelEncoder()
   y = enc.fit_transform(labels)
   vec = DictVectorizer()

   feat_sel = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=200)    

   n_classes = 3

# Pipeline for computing of ROC curves                 
  clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg', multi_class='multinomial'))
  clf = clf.label_binarizer_
  pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer', vec),
             ('scaler', scaler),
             ('Logreg', clf),
             ('mutual_info',feat_sel)])

  y_pred = model_selection.cross_val_predict(pipe, instances, y, cv=10) 


  fpr = dict()
  tpr = dict()
  roc_auc = dict()
  for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Plot of a ROC curve for a specific class
for i in range(n_classes):
     plt.figure()
     plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[i])
     plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
     plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
     plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
     plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
     plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
     plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
     plt.legend(loc="lower right")
     plt.show()
```

I thought I could binarize my y_pred by using the attribute `label_binarizer_` for the OneVsRestclassifier as mentioned here: [sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestclassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#examples-using-sklearn-multiclass-onevsrestclassifier).

However, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'label_binarizer_'`. I don't get this error, because the documentation tells me that it is an
attribute from this classifier.

when I add `instances = DataFrame(instances)` and `clf.fit(instances, y)`, I get the error: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`
. Instances is a list of feature vector dictionaries. I tried adding `instances = np.array(instances)` instead, but this gives me this error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not fit the `clf `.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't seem to understand multiclass ROC at all. Take the cross validation out and try to compute the multiclass ROC again. Hint: you cannot possibly "Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class", it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Calimo Since I'm just starting to learn about computational linguistics, so programming is new to me. I do have problems understanding multiclass ROC. I thought that since I want to evaluate a cross-validated model, that I needed to put crossvalidation into the calculation of the ROC curve

Comment: @Bambi make sure you understand all the parts individually before you piece them together in a cross-validation scheme. Otherwise it becomes impossible to understand, as you're realizing.

Comment: @VivekKumar Didn't I do that already in the pipeline with `vec = DictVectorizer()`?

Answer (score 5):

**You can use `label_binarizer` this way and get the desired plot as output.**

***Example using Iris data:***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y_bin = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y_bin.shape[1]

pipe= Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', LogisticRegression())])
# or
#clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
#pipe= Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', clf)])
y_score = cross_val_predict(pipe, X, y, cv=10 ,method='predict_proba')

fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_bin[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
colors = cycle(['blue', 'red', 'green'])
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
             label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic for multi-class data')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image]