# How to get multi-class roc_auc in cross validate in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a classification problem where I want to get the `roc_auc` value using `cross_validate` in sklearn. My code is as follows.

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = ('accuracy', 'roc_auc'))
```

However, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Please note that I selected `roc_auc` specifically is that it supports both `binary` and `multiclass` classification as mentioned in: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

I have binary classification dataset too. Please let me know how to resolve this error.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `multi_class='raise'` so you need **explicitly** to change this.

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_scoremulti_class):

> **multi_class *{‘raise’, ‘ovr’, ‘ovo’}, default=’raise’***
>
> Multiclass only. Determines the type of configuration to use. The
>   default value raises an error, so either 'ovr' or 'ovo' must be passed
>   explicitly.
>
> `'ovr'`:
>
> Computes the AUC of each class against the rest [3] [4]. This treats
>   the multiclass case in the same way as the multilabel case. Sensitive
>   to class imbalance even when `average == 'macro'`, because class
>   imbalance affects the composition of each of the ‘rest’ groupings.
>
> `'ovo'`:
>
> Computes the average AUC of all possible pairwise combinations of
>   classes [5]. Insensitive to class imbalance when `average == 'macro'`.

---

### Solution:

Use `make_scorer` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_scoremulti_class)):

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

myscore = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, multi_class='ovo',needs_proba=True)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = myscore)
```

Comment: This gives `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1` in `cross_validate`. You need to add `needs_proba=True` in the definition of `myscore`. Additionally, it's good practice to shuffle the data first.

Comment: @makis Thank you very much for the answer. However, I get the following error `TypeError: roc_auc_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multi_class'`. Is there a way to resolve this? :)

Comment: @makis One further question. If i want to use this for binary classification, what is the change I should do? Thank you :)

Comment: In sklearn 0.22.2 the function `roc_auc_score` has this argument. Make sure you upgrade your package. see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

Comment: @makis Thanks a lot. If I were to use your code for binary clsiification, is it correct if I make the scorer without `multi_class` parameter? i.e. `myscore = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba=True)`. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @makis Thanks a lot. I followed your answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641409/computing-scikit-learn-multiclass-roc-curve-with-cross-validation-cv and I got different results. Since there is limited space in the comments, I posted it as a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849396/how-to-get-roc-auc-for-binary-classification-in-sklearn Please let me know your thoughts on this :)

Comment: consider upvoting my answer. I am going to have a look at your newly posted question asap